# OpenCV get subimages by mask

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

Have you any ideas how can I with python and OpenCV get subimages on original image by that mask? I need separated subimages of every white area. 
Because it's not rects it's hard to get them separated.[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for connectedComponentsWithStats(), which will give you connected components (i.e., one label per white area). The result will be a labeled image with a separate label for each component.

From this, it is easy to extract the part of the image with a specific label.